# Sort objects of only one class in a mixed list

Tags: java, sorting

Consider the following list of objects which are from two classes (`A` and `C`),

> C3, A2, C1, A1, A3

I would like to sort only the objects of type `A` (with the objects of other types remain in their places) so the output would look 
like this:

> C3, A1, C1, A2, A3

Is there any ***straightforward*** way to do so in Java?

P.S. By straightforward, I mean, without implementation of custom algorithms and by using Java classes.

Comment: checkout bubble sort and add your custom logic https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: so you want to rearrange only `A`-s, so other objects leave on their positions?

Comment: @AlexSalauyou Yes, Alex.

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi no such method in JDK. What you need is not actually sorting, it is a combination of mapping + ordering

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can come up with a `Comparator` that incorporates the logic to do this, and certainly not a straightforward comparator. So just sorting the original array without writing your own sorting algorithm seems to be out.

My approach would be to generate a second array by stripping out the `C` elements (so it contains only the `A` elements), sort it using the standard Java classes, and then re-insert the `C` elements in their correct positions. You will have to be a little careful about indexing, as you are changing the sorted array length as you insert elements, but it should be fairly straightforward to work out.

Comment: you won't invent such comparator :) unless it holds initial positions of all elements. Because there is no such ordering relation here that depends only on object type/value.

Comment: What about having interface with a method plus custom comparator, depending upon the output of the method you can skip uninterested class types and continue to sort others...

Comment: Thank you sir, the problem with your approach is that, in practice, the array is large in size and such insertions would incur a high overhead.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou - Exactly. I was thinking about a comparator that maintained an internal map of objects to their original index. But even then that won't help because one `A` value might jump around before or after any particular `C` value based on what other `A` values are encountered. So even an index map doesn't really help build such a comparator.

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi - Yes, that can be an issue. It's a little more overhead, but you can do the following after sorting: make a `LinkedList` from the sorted second array; insert the elements into the `LinkedList` (very low insertion overhead); then, if necessary, copy the result back into an array or an `ArrayList`. Alternatively (and probably better), you can "merge" the original list (ignoring the `A` values) with the sorted second list to create a third list. In either approach, there's some copying involved, but the overall complexity remains at O(n log n).

Comment: Perhaps a PriorityQueue<A> with an appropriate Comparator<A>, then iterate the List and put all type A objects in the queue, then iterate the List again (using a for loop to have an index) and for each A in the List, list.set(i, queue.pop()).

Comment: @AndrewS - Yes, a `PriorityQueue` can be used to eliminate one line of code (a call to a sort routine). However, the overall complexity isn't going to be any better because in the end, after you first offer and then poll (not pop) every element in the priority queue, you've basically just done a heap sort.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the simplest solution, but one (hacked together*) approach:

Add all `A` objects to a new `List` and sort them:

```
List<A> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(a2);
list2.add(a1);
list2.add(a3);
Collections.sort(list2, new Comparator<A>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(A a1, A a2) {
        return a1.getName().compareTo(a2.getName());
    }
});
```

And then have a final list, adding from the original list if the type is `C` and otherwise add from the sorted `A` list:

```
List<Object> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();
int it = 0;
for (Object obj : list) {
    if (obj instanceof C) {
       resultSet.add(obj);
   } else {
       resultSet.add(list2.get(it));
        it++;
    }
```

}

[**Example**](https://ideone.com/yipgMo)

*<sup>Note that this is just to get an idea of how to do it, not a great solution to copy.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it as you would normally sort a list, but you would use `.getClass()` and `.getClass().getSimpleName()` to tell if they're in class A or C, and what name the instance has

Comment: And how would you decide if an `A` element comes before or after a `C` element during the sort?

Comment: Yes sorry I guess I misunderstood the question, I thought they were having trouble  with the 'identify class names' part rather than the actual sorting algorithm